# Period of sum of three trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry, periodic-functions

am trying to compute the period of the following:
$$\cos(\pi t) + 2\cos(3\pi t) + 3\cos(5\pi t)$$

I know that given two sinusoids, the period is found from the ratio of the two sinusoids. but here:

$$\text{(period of the first term) }T_1 = 2$$
$$\text{(period of the second term) }T_2= 2/3$$
$$\text{(period of the third term) }T_3= 2/5$$

but where should I go from here. Can somebody please show me a general formula
whenever I encounter a question that asks for the period of the product or sum of multiple sinusoids. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Call the function in question $f(t)$. You're trying to find the smallest positive value of $a$ such that $f(t + a) = f(t)$ for all values of $t$. Depending on the level at which your course is being taught, you may just need to find $a$ and not prove rigorously that it's the smallest possible. Can you find a value of $a$ such that if you replace $t$ with $t + a$, the value of the function doesn't change?

Comment: this is at the pre-calculus level. Its been taught finding the period for two trig functions being multiplied or added together, but not for more than two

Comment: When you say that your answer for the second term would be $2/3$, what that means is that if you take the expression $2 \cos 3\pi t$ and you replace $t$ with $t + 2/3$ in it, then the value of the expression doesn't change (and that $2/3$ can't be replaced with a smaller positive number that would also work). You should try replacing $t$ with $t + 2/3$ to see how this works. What you're trying to do is find a number that would work like $2/3$ here, except that the whole sum taken together isn't supposed to change.

Answer (score 1):

$$2,\frac{2}{3},\frac{2}{5}\to\\\dfrac{30}{15},\dfrac{10}{15},\dfrac{6}{15}\\$$now factor $\dfrac{2}{15}$so 
$$T_{total}=\dfrac{2}{15}\underbrace{[15,5,3]}_{lcm}=\\\dfrac{2}{15}\times3\times5=2$$

Comment: This is a general method, as requested. It's probably worth remarking that "lcm" means you take the least common multiple of the three integers. Also note that you don't have to be so clever about finding the largest possible factor; if you only factor out $\frac1{15}$ then you end up taking the LCM of $30,10,6,$ which is $30,$ multiply by $\frac1{15}$ and you get $2.$ The main thing is to get all three periods as integer multiples of some known value.

Answer (score 0):

For the first function , the periods are

$$\color {red}{2}, 4, 6, 8, 10...$$
for the second
$$2/3, 4/3, \color {red}{2}, 8/3,... $$
and for the third

$$2/5, 4/5, 6/5, 8/5,\color {red}{ 2},... $$

the smallest common period is $$T=2$$